# Outline shown by PDF viewer is incorrect

Tags: table-of-contents, books

I'm trying to structure my book as shown by the TOC below. However, as you can also see in the screenshot below, the outline from the PDF Viewer is incorrect.

[image]

The underlying LaTeX code I used is:

```latex
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\part{First part}

This is the first part.

\chapter{First chapter in first part}

This is the first chapter in the first part.

\section{Section in first chapter}

\part{Second part}

This is the second part.

\chapter{First chapter in second part}

This is the first chapter in the second part.

\part*{Appendix}
\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{Appendix}
\setcounter{chapter}{0} % Reset numbering for chapter

\chapter{First chapter in appendix}

This is the first chapter in the appendix.

\section{Section in appendix}

\end{document}
```

I am happy for any pointers. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get warnings in the log:

```
pdfTeX warning (ext4): destination with the same identifier (name{ch
apter.1}) has been already used, duplicate ignored
<to be read again> 
                   \relax 
l.46 \chapter{First chapter in appendix}
```

Such warnings should be taken seriously. They always mean that something in the internal link structure is confused.

You can make the name of the destinations unique by redefining \theHchapter:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\part{First part}

This is the first part.

\chapter{First chapter in first part}

This is the first chapter in the first part.

\section{Section in first chapter}

\part{Second part}

This is the second part.

\chapter{First chapter in second part}

This is the first chapter in the second part.

\part*{Appendix}
\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{Appendix}
\renewcommand\theHchapter{Appendix.\thechapter}
\setcounter{chapter}{0} % Reset numbering for chapter

\chapter{First chapter in appendix}

This is the first chapter in the appendix.

\section{Section in appendix}

\end{document}
```

And then the bookmarks will be correct too:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your prompt solution, Ulrike! You're right, I overlooked that warning. Nevertheless, with your fix everything works as expected. :-)